# Subtotal with 2 criteria

Tags: excel-formula, subtotal

How to subtotal count of 2 criteria?

Ex. as per the screenshot:

[Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNvUt.jpg)

I want subtotal count of "LONG" in "G" column & "Net P/L" should be > 0

Both criteria need to be satisfied

*******=Subtotal "LONG" & "profit >0".*******

Answer (score 0):

**MODIFIED ANSWER**

Based on the need to have the filter applied to the result, this is a modification of the formula you presented:

```
=SUM( (Table6[[#All],[LONG/SHORT]]="LONG")*(Table6[[#All],[NET P/L]]>0)*
          (SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Table6[[#Headers],[LONG/SHORT]],
                             ROW(Table6[[#All],[LONG/SHORT]]) - MIN(ROW(Table6[[#All],[LONG/SHORT]] ) ),
                             0) ) ) )
```

I added `(Table6[[#All],[NET P/L]]>0)*` to the condition. You can add any number of additional filters in the same way. NB: I converted the SUMPRODUCT to SUM because sum is sufficient.

This may need to be entered as an array formula if you have Excel 2013 or lower. *(CTRL SHIFT ENTER)*

Here is the result using an OTHER column to filter the data:

[image: result]

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

You can do either COUNTIFS or use a SUM with boolean conditions.

```
=COUNTIFS( V2:V26, ">0", G2:G26, "LONG" )
```

or

```
=SUM((V2:V26>0)*(G2:G26="LONG"))
```

If you want it to act like SUBTOTAL, then you can emulate SUBTOTAL by forcing the formula to look only at cells with raw data like this:

```
=SUM((V2:V26>0)*(G2:G26="LONG")*NOT(ISFORMULA( V2:V26 )))
```

But this will not work if column V has formulas.

Comment: Thanks for Reply. But i want the count of only filtered rows by using SUBTOTAL formula. Can you Help me with that??

Comment: I Found formula for one crieteria like this                                                                                          --                                                                                               =SUMPRODUCT((Table1[[#All],[Long/Short]]="LONG")*(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Table1[[#Headers],[Long/Short]],ROW(Table1[[#All],[Long/Short]])-MIN(ROW(Table1[[#All],[Long/Short]])),0))))                                                                          - . But I want Subtotal for 2 Crieteria (Long & P/L >0)

Comment: Now I see what you want - it is not so much the subtotalling as it is the response to filtering and that explains why SUBTOTAL. This is an interesting problem and the formula above is really clever.  I will post a modified version that I think it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((G3:G5000="LONG")*(V3:V5000>0)*SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(V2,ROW(V3:V5000)-ROW(V2),)))
```

The 103 in SUBTOTAL will exclude filtered rows.

This is an array formula. Input it into the cell and then press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to create the array formula.